# check decimal format in .tsx

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, tsx

I’m  currently looking for a way to check the format of a number.

I want to accept only conventional decimals such as: { 1 ; 1.1 ; 1.01 ; 15 ; 15.15}.

Currently in my text box I can pass numbers like for example: 102.129.392.12 (like an ip adress indeed) etc...

I had thought to put a regex to check that the format is good:

```
. .match(/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/)
```

but I don’t know how to implement it in a .tsx file

I’m new to react's technology.

Here's my code.

```
const SupplyEvent = () => {

   const handleChangeQuantity = (value: string) => {
       if (chosenSupply) {
          setChosenSupply({
            ...chosenSupply,
            quantity: value.replace(/,/g, '.'),
            // .match(/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/)
          });
       }
  }; 

  return(
     <View style={styles.halfWidth}>
        <Input
           value={chosenSupply?.quantity}
           keyboardType="decimal-pad"
           onChangeText={handleChangeQuantity}
           disabled={mode === FormMode.read}
        />
     </View>
   );
};
```

I want to add a message in red for the user like 'This number is not accepted'

Do you guys have any ideas ?

Thanks you

Comment: Hi, please what's the use of this part of code > value.replace(/,/g, '.')

Comment: because in french we use coma to separate decimal value.
1,2 become 1.2 in english
I need to allow my users to write 1,2 then i replace come with point

Comment: I see, try the solution below it may work for you

Answer (score 0):

```
...
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

const SupplyEvent = () => {
   const [error, setError] = useState(null);

   const handleChangeQuantity = (value: string) => {
       const resolveValue = value.replace(/,/g, '.');

       if(!resolveValue.match(/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?$/)){
          setError("Format isn't correct");
       }
       else if (chosenSupply) {
          setChosenSupply((prevChosenSupply)=>({
            ...prevChosenSupply,
            quantity: resolveValue
          }));
       }
  }; 

  return(
     <View style={styles.halfWidth}>
        {error && <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{error}</Text>}
        <Input
           value={chosenSupply?.quantity}
           keyboardType="decimal-pad"
           onChangeText={handleChangeQuantity}
           disabled={mode === FormMode.read}
        />
     </View>
   );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ...
  errorMessage: {
    color: 'white',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    borderRadius: 5
  }
});
```